# How do I deploy BPMN process to process engine with Camunda Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, bpmn, camunda

I have built a Camunda BPM with Spring Boot as a Standalone Process Engine, it will be waiting some requests for starting process from other web applications

now, my co-works have design a few processes in BPMN Tools, I think I should use the REST API deploy these BPMN to Standalone Process Engine, how can I do? or other solution which allows uploading BPMN files to Standalone Process Engine?

Is there any example?

We want to use Camunda BPM in our Application, so we have to solve some problems

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

When you are using Spring Boot as an application container, do you really need to deploy processes at runtime? It seems to me that the common scenario in this case would be "bundle the processes and the application and deploy on startup". If you need to change or add processes, just stop, repackage and start your Camunda Spring Boot application. To do this, the [`SpringProcessEngineConfiguration`](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.3/org/camunda/bpm/engine/spring/SpringProcessEngineConfiguration.html) allows setting `deploymentResources`.

If you really need to change processes at runtime, make sure you add the REST API to your Spring Boot bundle and follow https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.3/api-references/rest/#deployment-post-deployment.

We also  have created a Camunda community extension that makes dealing with Camunda and Spring Boot a lot simpler: https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter

Comment: Care to comment the downvote? Is something wrong/outdated? Then please leave a hint ...

Comment: There are definitely scenarios where you want o deploy processes without requiring a redeploy of the spring boot application!

Comment: I am with you ... but I believe those are less common than the complete re-boot ... and as I mentioned, you can use the rest api to do so.